# Why is a simple insert into Postgres from Flyway causing duplicate key value violation?

Tags: postgresql, flyway

When I run my flyway script to insert into a table in PostgreSQL 10.0 I get a duplicate key value violates unique constraint and I can't understand why

The SQL (V1.1.2__insert_candy.sql)

```
insert into candy(candy, name) values ('BUTTERCUP','Peanut Butter Cup')
```

The Table

```
CREATE SEQUENCE candy_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE candy
(
  id            int primary key not null default nextval('candy_id_seq'),
  name          text not null,
  candy         text,
  last_modified timestamp with time zone default now()
);
```

Table values

```
id  name             candy            last_modified
1   Sucker           SUCKER           2018-01-26 00:28:36.763462
2   Peanut Brittle   PEANUT_BRITTLE   2018-01-26 00:28:36.763462
3   Chocolate Cream  CHOCOLATE_CREAM  2018-01-26 00:28:36.763462
4   S'mores          SMORES           2018-01-26 00:28:37.418496
5   Candy Apple      CANDY_APPLE      2018-01-26 00:28:38.464321
6   Carmel Apple     CARMEL_APPLE     2018-01-26 00:28:38.998292
7   Sugar Free       SUGAR_FREE       2018-01-26 00:28:39.225477
```

There error

```
Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource 
dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException: 
Migration V1.1.2__insert_candy.sql failed
--------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 23505
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "candy_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(7) already exists.
Line       : 1
Statement  : insert into candy(candy, name) values ('BUTTERCUP','Peanut Butter Cup')
```

If I just run the statement directly all works well.

When I delete the manually inserted row I can run the flyway script without any issues.

Comment: Does it happen when flyway runs against a clean database? The only reason that it fails would be someone manually inserting row `id=7` as sequences are never rolled back.

Comment: So I'm kinda a noob, but you are right! I did a select * from candy_id_seq; and sure enough last_value is 6 not 7 running SELECT pg_catalog.setval('candy_id_seq', 7, true); to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @Karol Dowbecki's comment I checked the sequence (I didn't even know that was a thing)

```
select * from candy_id_seq;
```

And sure enough ID sequence is 6 instead of 7.

```
sequence_name | last_value | start_value | increment_by |      max_value      | min_value | cache_value | log_cnt | is_cycled | is_called 
---------------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------
candy_id_seq   |          6 |           1 |            1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 |           1 |      27 | f         | t
(1 row)
```

This was caused by someone explicitly assigning ID on an insert a previous flyway script

```
INSERT INTO candy
SELECT 7, 'Sugar Free', 'SUGAR_FREE'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from candy where candy.candy = 'SUGAR_FREE');
```

To fix this I added this to my flyway script

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('candy_id_seq', 7, true);
```

I still feel this is a little bit risky because I'm explicitly setting the candy_id_seq, but it will get me back moving.

Thank you for your help.